# Normable topology on a finite demensional locally convex space

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from Royden's Real Analysis.
Show that the topology on a finite dimensional locally convex topological vector space is induced by a norm. I think this should be a well known result but I can not find any reference that gives a detailed proof of this property. And I have not seen any technique to prove a topology is normable. Any help will be appreciated.

From Royden's book, A locally convex topological vector space is a Hausdorff space, with the 3 additional properties:

1.the addition map $X\times X \to X$, $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is continuous

2.the scalar multiplication map $\mathbb{R}\times X \to X$, $(k,x)\mapsto kx$ is continuous

3.for any open set $O$ that contains the origin $0$, there is a convex neighborhood around $0$, denoted by $N$, which is also an element of the topological base, such that $N$ is contained in $O$.

Comment: Can you do something like this: pick a basis $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ for the space. Write $x = a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n$ and define $||x|| = |a_1 + \cdots + a_n|$?

Answer (score 5):

Let $E$ be the locally convex finite dimensional topological space, let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be a basis for $E$, and let $\mathbb R^n$ be given the standard topology.

Since multiplication by a scalar and addition of vectors is continuous on $E$, it follows that the map $I:\mathbb R^n \to E$, $(x_i)_{i=1}^n \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i$ is continous.

Now consider the closed unit ball $B \subset \mathbb R^n$.  Then the restriction of $I$ to $B$ is a continuous bijection that maps a compact topological space to a Hausdorff topological space.  Hence it is a homeomorphism.

So we need to show that the map $I$ is open on all of $E$.  Since $I$ is a homeomorphism from $B$ to $I(B)$, it follows that $\epsilon I(B^\circ)$ is a base of neighbourhoods of $0$ in $I(B)$.  Hence by the definition of the subspace topology, and since $E$ is locally convex, for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, there exists an open, convex neighbourhood $N_\epsilon$ of $0$ in $E$ such that $N_\epsilon \cap I(B) \subset \epsilon I(B^\circ)$.

Now suppose that $N_\epsilon \setminus I(B) \ne \emptyset$.  Then pick $x \in N_\epsilon \setminus I(B)$.  Then $\|I^{-1}(x)\| \ge 1$.  Since $0 \in N_\epsilon$, the line segment $[0,x] \subset N_\epsilon$.  But then $N_\epsilon$ contains elements whose preimages under $I$ have norm strictly between $1$ and $\epsilon$, contradicting that $N_\epsilon \cap I(B) \subset \epsilon I(B^\circ)$.

Hence $N_\epsilon \subset \epsilon I(B^\circ)$.

Hence any neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$ maps to an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $E$.  Hence $I$ is an open map on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: The OP is not asking about $\mathbb{R}^n$ specifically, but an arbitrary finite dimensional locally convex topological vector space.

Comment: @wckronholm Presumably he means for the finite dimensional locally convex topological vector space to be a vector space over the reals.  Otherwise, how would you define "locally convex"?  And any finite dimensional vector space over the reals is algebraically equivalent to $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I agree. I guess I think that should be part of the answer somehow.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help. I have added the definition of a locally convex topological vector space to my first post. As we shall see, a locally convex topological vector space is an extension of a normed linear space.

Comment: @wckronholm So what about this edit?

Comment: If Hausdorff is one of the axioms, I don't see where I need to use "locally convex."

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I like it!

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith,thanks for the help. But I still have trouble on the statement"a continuous bijection that maps a compact topological space to a Hausdorff topological space. Hence it is a homeomorphism". My concern is showing the inverse of I is continuous which is equivalent to showing that I is open. By the bijection property, it suffices to show I maps a closed set to a closed set. Now if C is closed in B, then C is compact, hence I(C) is compact hence closed. But this argument does not use the Hausdorff property of the image space. I worry my method is false.

Comment: @wckronholm I added the details, which were harder than I thought, and needed the local convexity.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, My bad! I need Hausdoff property to claim a compact set is closed. Sorry.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith, you have given an interesting answer to this post which was posted five ago. But I think the locally convex is not necessary, since we can aways find an balanaced open neigborhood inclued in $N_\epsilon$ given by you.

Comment: Would you please add more detail explaining why the result that $N_\epsilon\subset\epsilon I(B^\circ)$ implies that any neighbourhood of $0$ in $\Bbb R^n$ maps to an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $E$.

Comment: @user0 I think you are correct.  How about if instead I say any neighborhood of $0$ maps to a set containing an open neighborhood of $0$ in $E$.  And do you agree that the final conclusion is still correct?

Comment: The second sentence in your comment is OK (it follows from inclusion $N_\epsilon\subset\epsilon I(B^\circ)$ and the fact that sets of type $\epsilon B^\circ$ form a base at the origin for the topology on $\Bbb R^n$), but I cannot yet see how it implies that $I$ is an open map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $E$ (which I assume is correct because it is a textbook problem).

Comment: @user0 Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$.  Let $I(x)$ be any point in $E$.  Let $x + \epsilon B$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ contained in $U$.  Then $I(x + \epsilon B)$ contains an open neighborhood of $I(x)$ in $I(U)$.

Answer (score 0):

I can slightly modify the proof given by@Stephen Montgomery-Smith. Then the locally convex is not necessary in the original post.

Let's cite the process in Stephen's answer. Now we acknowledge that the mapping $I$  from the closed unit ball $B \subset \mathbb R^n$ to $I(B)$ is a homeomorphism. Now we need to show that the map $I$ is an open mapping.

Since $B^\circ$ is an open neighbourhood in $B$, there is an open, balanced  neighbourhood $N$ of $0$ in $E$ such that $N \cap I(B) \subset I(B^\circ)$.

In a same way with Stephen, suppose that $N \setminus I(B) \ne \emptyset$.  Then picking $x \in N \setminus I(B)$, we have $\|I^{-1}(x)\| > 1$.  Since $N$ is balanced, $\frac{x}{\|I^{-1}~(x)\|}$ is still in $N$. Notice that $\|I^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\|I^{-1}~(x)\|}\right)\| =1$. Then $\frac{x}{\|I^{-1}~(x)\|}$ is also in $I(B)$. It follows that $\frac{x}{\|I^{-1}~(x)\|}$ is also in $I(B^\circ)$, contradicting that $\|I^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\|I^{-1}~(x)\|}\right)\| =1$. Hence $N \subset  I(B^\circ)$.

Moreover from this we can deduce that any neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$ maps to an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $E$.