# In a finite-dimentional Hausdorff locally convex vector space, how to prove there exists a seminorm which is a norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let E be a finite-dimensional Hausdorff locally convex vector space, and $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ is its basis. I know that from the Hausdorff and locally convexity, there exists a seminorm $p$ satisfying that  $p(e_1)\geq 1,\ldots$, and $p(e_n)\geq 1$. I want to prove that for any $x\neq 0$, $p(x)>0$. This immediately means that $p$ is a continous norm on this tvs.

By the way, I know that a finite-dimensional locally convex vector space can be induced by a norm. This has been discussed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715114/normable-topology-on-a-finite-demensional-locally-convex-space) post. @Stephen Montgomery-Smith has posted a detailed solution. But I really want to prove that:

If $p(e_1)\geq 1,\ldots$, and $p(e_n)\geq 1$, then for any $x\neq 0$, $p(x)>0$.

In fact, if the above is true, then the fact that a finite-dimensional locally convex vector space can be induced by a norm would be proved more directly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the functional
$$\omega: E \to \mathbb{C}: \sum_i \alpha_i e_i \mapsto \sum_i \alpha_i.$$

Then $p(x) = |\omega(x)|$ is a seminorm. Note that
$$p(e_i) = 1$$
for all $i$ but we have $p(e_1-e_2) = |\omega(e_1-e_2)| = 0$
so your claim does not hold.

---

However, proving that $E$ admits a norm is quite easy. For example, define
$$\left\|\sum_i \alpha_i e_i\right\|:= \sum_i |\alpha_i|.$$

Comment: many thanks! You give me an specific example to deny my question! However, it is not easy to prove than $\sum_i |\alpha_i|$ is continuous on the locally t.v.s. I want to clirify that "In a Hausdorff locally convex t.v.s, whether there exists a continuous seminorm p which is a norm", and this seminorm can be constructed directly!